# Task.Factory.StartNew<TResult> (Func<Object, TResult>, object state) build error

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, task-parallel-library

when I compile the code I get this error, I couldn't figure out why mcs looks for the wrong function overload, I'm using mono as latest of current active development version from git, I checked the TaskFactory class source code and the function exists !

---

> TaskPoc.cs(30,20): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for ``System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew<bool>(System.Func<bool>, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCreationOptions)`' has some invalid arguments
>   /usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
>   TaskPoc.cs(30,56): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert ``System.Func<TaskPoc.State,bool>`' expression to type ``System.Func<bool>`'

---

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace TaskPoc
{
  public class State
  {
    public int num;
    public string str;
  }

  public class App
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      State state = new State();
      state.num = 5;
      state.str = "Helllllllllllo";

      TaskCompletionSource<bool> taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(state);
      Task<bool> taskObj = taskCompletionSource.Task;

      Func<State, bool> userMethod = (stateObj) =>
        {
            bool result = TestMethod(stateObj.num, stateObj.str);
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(result);
            return result;
        };

      Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(userMethod, state);

      bool result2 = taskObj.Result;
      Console.WriteLine("Result: ", result2.ToString());
    }

    public static bool TestMethod(int num, string str)
    {
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", num, str));
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want this overload: [TaskFactory.StartNew<TResult>(Func<Object, TResult>, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321394.aspx)

As you can see, the argument of the `Func<Object, TResult>` must be `Object`, not `State`.

You can fix your code as follows:

```
Func<object, bool> userMethod = (state) =>
{
    State stateObj = (State)state;
    bool result = TestMethod(stateObj.num, stateObj.str);
    taskCompletionSource.SetResult(result);
    return result;
};
```

---

Note that your code can be shortened as follows:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num = 5;
    string str = "Helllllllllllo";

    Task<bool> taskObj = Task.Run<bool>(() => TestMethod(num, str));

    bool result2 = taskObj.Result;
    Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result2);
}
```